# Wordpress plugin using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm starting to get into WordPress and looking at developing some plugins.

If I want my plugin to use a specific version of jQuery how do I enable that?

ie. some themes don't use jQuery, some use OLD versions - what if I need a more recent version?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

I've seen the code above suggested - but will that only load whatever jQuery is in the theme folders already (if at all)?

Is it better to include a jQuery.js file with my plugin, and reference it directly from my plugin code?  If, so, how would I change the script above, to load MY version of jQuery?

Thank you for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest WordPress 4.0 comes with jQuery 1.11.1.

But in case you want to remove the WordPress default jQuery library with say either a local new JS or a CDN you can do so by placing the following code in either a plugin or your theme's functions.php

```
function jquery_cdn() {
   if (!is_admin()) {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', 'jQuery_JS_PATH', false, '1.8.3');
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
add_action('init', 'jquery_cdn');
```

References:

http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/4.0/wp-includes/js/jquery/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

http://agilewp.com/how-to/remove-wordpress-jquery-and-use-googles-cdn-version-instead/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I wonder why WP comes with 1.11.1 when the latest version is 2.x - Cheers, Mark

Comment: jQuery 2.x does not have support for IE 6.7 and 8, which is why WordPress does not use it. Refer: http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x

Comment: Some jQuery-dependent plugins (and probably many of them) won't work with such an old version of jQuery. What were they thinking? Why deliberately including an old version that will inevitably cause problems?